# Using googlecl inside Python script to d/l Google doc

Tags: python, googlecl

subprocess.check_output(('/Applications/googlecl-0.9.13/build/scripts-2.7/google', 'docs', 'get', r'"Reassessment Request"', r'--format', 'csv', r'/Users/myaccount/Desktop'), shell=True)

This code doesn't pull down the doc, but running the identical line will work inside Terminal. It might not be having time to complete? It takes a while when I run it from the command line.

There's a Python error:
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myaccount/Desktop/reassess2.py", line 17, in 
    subprocess.call('google docs get "Reassessment Request" --format csv /Users/myaccount/Desktop')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in **init**
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

I get a similar problem when I try to run it in an OSX script:
When I run the shell script (running the command line above), I get: 
?/Users/myaccount/Desktop/ReScript.sh ; exit;
.csvloading Reassessment Request to /users/myaccount/Desktop
logout

[Process completed]", 
but no file is actually downloaded.

OSX Mountain Lion; 0.9.13 cl; 2.0.17 gdata (I think - not the most recent, but the one that works with cl)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google CL is pretty much on its way out, and the new form update to Google drive has broken it for these types of operations. I used Gdata as a workaround for a while, but if anyone is trying to use either of those and stumbles onto this, here's the best current answer: [Gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread). It installs easily (unlike the others, which had tricky version compatibility issues), requires less code, and is faster.

With Gspread, this code would be replaced by:

```
username = 'jimjam@gmail.com'
password = 'bwdfsdfsafadlhsw'
sheetname = "Reassessment Requesttemp"

client = gspread.login(username, password)
spreadsheet = client.open(sheetname)

worksheet = spreadsheet.sheet1
contents = worksheet.get_all_values()
```